# Get Device id using ipmitool failed

Tags: ipmitool

I'm executing below command for getting Device ID from BMC but I got error Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1)

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.0.147 -U root -P root raw 0x06 0x01
Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1)
```

I have give verbose option to ipmitool and got below output

```
>> Sending IPMI command payload
>>    netfn   : 0x06
>>    command : 0x38
>>    data    : 0x8e 0x04 

BUILDING A v1.5 COMMAND
>> IPMI Request Session Header
>>   Authtype   : NONE
>>   Sequence   : 0x00000000
>>   Session ID : 0x00000000
>> IPMI Request Message Header
>>   Rs Addr    : 20
>>   NetFn      : 06
>>   Rs LUN     : 0
>>   Rq Addr    : 81
>>   Rq Seq     : 00
>>   Rq Lun     : 0
>>   Command    : 38
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype                : NONE
<<   Payload type            : IPMI (0)
<<   Session ID              : 0x00000000
<<   Sequence                : 0x00000000
<<   IPMI Msg/Payload Length : 16
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 81
<<   NetFn      : 07
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 00
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 38
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
>> SENDING AN OPEN SESSION REQUEST

<<OPEN SESSION RESPONSE
<<  Message tag                        : 0x00
<<  RMCP+ status                       : no errors
<<  Maximum privilege level            : Unknown (0x00)
<<  Console Session ID                 : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<  BMC Session ID                     : 0x0000000d
<<  Negotiated authenticatin algorithm : hmac_sha1
<<  Negotiated integrity algorithm     : hmac_sha1_96
<<  Negotiated encryption algorithm    : aes_cbc_128

>> Console generated random number (16 bytes)
 26 83 1b f2 7c 7b cc 16 c6 b7 a4 25 15 e9 ce 2f
>> SENDING A RAKP 1 MESSAGE

<<RAKP 2 MESSAGE
<<  Message tag                   : 0x00
<<  RMCP+ status                  : no errors
<<  Console Session ID            : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<  BMC random number             : 0x64653a3a706172736552504352657370
<<  BMC GUID                      : 0xcdc69bb454110e827441213ddc8770e9
<<  Key exchange auth code [sha1] : 0x03f1426e8c607acffc47cd02cae04cee04017244

bmc_rand (16 bytes)
 64 65 3a 3a 70 61 72 73 65 52 50 43 52 65 73 70
>> rakp2 mac input buffer (68 bytes)
 a4 a3 a2 a0 0d 00 00 00 26 83 1b f2 7c 7b cc 16
 c6 b7 a4 25 15 e9 ce 2f 64 65 3a 3a 70 61 72 73
 65 52 50 43 52 65 73 70 cd c6 9b b4 54 11 0e 82
 74 41 21 3d dc 87 70 e9 14 0a 69 70 6d 69 5f 61
 64 6d 69 6e
>> rakp2 mac key (20 bytes)
 31 40 61 64 25 38 39 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00
>> rakp2 mac as computed by the remote console (20 bytes)
 03 f1 42 6e 8c 60 7a cf fc 47 cd 02 ca e0 4c ee
 04 01 72 44
>> rakp3 mac input buffer (32 bytes)
 64 65 3a 3a 70 61 72 73 65 52 50 43 52 65 73 70
 a4 a3 a2 a0 14 0a 69 70 6d 69 5f 61 64 6d 69 6e
>> rakp3 mac key (20 bytes)
 31 40 61 64 25 38 39 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00
generated rakp3 mac (20 bytes)
 ea f8 3a 58 12 41 8a 5c 7c 53 98 9f 92 aa f2 bb
 1c b5 85 04
session integrity key input (44 bytes)
 26 83 1b f2 7c 7b cc 16 c6 b7 a4 25 15 e9 ce 2f
 64 65 3a 3a 70 61 72 73 65 52 50 43 52 65 73 70
 14 0a 69 70 6d 69 5f 61 64 6d 69 6e
Generated session integrity key (20 bytes)
 a7 d8 c9 d4 28 37 01 ae ce d3 c9 69 be 71 d9 1c
 34 9f 96 b1
Generated K1 (20 bytes)
 60 1d ec ba 7e 8a 2d b0 d8 80 a1 96 d0 a0 0e bc
 a4 13 3e 03
Generated K2 (20 bytes)
 e0 6c 1d a7 b5 7e 39 3a 99 bb 13 17 9b d5 9f c5
 95 b0 b9 7d
>> SENDING A RAKP 3 MESSAGE

<<RAKP 4 MESSAGE
<<  Message tag                   : 0x00
<<  RMCP+ status                  : no errors
<<  Console Session ID            : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<  Key exchange auth code [sha1] : 0x2f0aca6d3a769dba27c34cb9

>> rakp4 mac input buffer (36 bytes)
 26 83 1b f2 7c 7b cc 16 c6 b7 a4 25 15 e9 ce 2f
 0d 00 00 00 cd c6 9b b4 54 11 0e 82 74 41 21 3d
 dc 87 70 e9
>> rakp4 mac key (sik) (20 bytes)
 a7 d8 c9 d4 28 37 01 ae ce d3 c9 69 be 71 d9 1c
 34 9f 96 b1
>> rakp4 mac as computed by the BMC (20 bytes)
 2f 0a ca 6d 3a 76 9d ba 27 c3 4c b9 52 65 73 70
 cd c6 9b b4
>> rakp4 mac as computed by the remote console (20 bytes)
 2f 0a ca 6d 3a 76 9d ba 27 c3 4c b9 6a cb ca b2
 2e ac d0 dc
IPMIv2 / RMCP+ SESSION OPENED SUCCESSFULLY


>> Sending IPMI command payload
>>    netfn   : 0x06
>>    command : 0x3b
>>    data    : 0x04 

BUILDING A v2 COMMAND
>> Initialization vector (16 bytes)
 d6 49 45 06 6b 80 ca a3 ac f0 00 d7 02 79 5f 26
authcode input (48 bytes)
 06 c0 0d 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 20 00 d6 49 45 06
 6b 80 ca a3 ac f0 00 d7 02 79 5f 26 6f d6 91 f4
 98 69 66 38 4d 66 cc c0 93 ce a2 57 ff ff 02 07
authcode output (12 bytes)
 25 b3 bc 24 94 a6 26 bf ba 6c 5f cc
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype                : Unknown (0x06)
<<   Payload type            : IPMI (0)
<<   Session ID              : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<   Sequence                : 0x00000003
<<   IPMI Msg/Payload Length : 32
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 81
<<   NetFn      : 07
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 01
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 3b
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
set_session_privlvl (1 bytes)
 04
Set Session Privilege Level to ADMINISTRATOR


>> Sending IPMI command payload
>>    netfn   : 0x06
>>    command : 0x01
>>    data    : 

BUILDING A v2 COMMAND
>> Initialization vector (16 bytes)
 bf 8b e8 8e 0a a9 22 1b 68 19 10 5e 95 53 4d 24
authcode input (48 bytes)
 06 c0 0d 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 20 00 bf 8b e8 8e
 0a a9 22 1b 68 19 10 5e 95 53 4d 24 8e 5e 0c 1e
 d8 44 bc 1e da d6 0b 2e a9 28 03 72 ff ff 02 07
authcode output (12 bytes)
 cd a5 7e 34 c2 04 99 11 38 74 d6 fb
Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1)

>> Sending IPMI command payload
>>    netfn   : 0x06
>>    command : 0x3c
>>    data    : 0x0d 0x00 0x00 0x00 

BUILDING A v2 COMMAND
>> Initialization vector (16 bytes)
 50 16 10 a4 b2 15 54 ac b5 0c bb 4f 25 cf 1d c0
authcode input (48 bytes)
 06 c0 0d 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 20 00 50 16 10 a4
 b2 15 54 ac b5 0c bb 4f 25 cf 1d c0 3e 97 5a f2
 80 5c dd 02 2f b8 c3 74 c2 9b 76 e9 ff ff 02 07
authcode output (12 bytes)
 79 f4 26 8d c2 93 1c cb 17 54 68 b2
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype                : Unknown (0x06)
<<   Payload type            : IPMI (0)
<<   Session ID              : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<   Sequence                : 0x00000004
<<   IPMI Msg/Payload Length : 48
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 20
<<   NetFn      : 06
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 39
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 01
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
IPMI Request Match NOT FOUND
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype                : Unknown (0x06)
<<   Payload type            : IPMI (0)
<<   Session ID              : 0xa0a2a3a4
<<   Sequence                : 0x00000005
<<   IPMI Msg/Payload Length : 32
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 81
<<   NetFn      : 07
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 03
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 3c
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
Closed Session 0000000d
```

Please let me know if anyone have idea about this issue

Comment: Can you check if there are any BMC firewall configured to block raw commands?

Answer (score 0):

I'm traversing forum for solution on my problem but in fact I think I know solution for this issue:

You miss two arguments: `-t` and `-b`.

`-t` - target address (this is BMC or host address to which you want send msg)

`-b` - destination channel (it depends from type of command, e.g. for `Get Device Id` channel is `6`

Try this:

`ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.0.147 -U root -P root -t 0x2c -b 6 raw 0x06 0x01`